# Twilio Forward calls to outside number, Then disconnect Twilio side

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, ivr

I was wondering if its possible to forward a call from our Twilio IVR to an outside number, then disconnect the Twilio side.
The reason for this is we are using a conferencing system to live stream an event. We do not want to incur Twilio charges from all the forwards staying the Twilio system.
At this point we have ruled out using a direct number for the live stream. We wanted it to route through our Main 1855 IVR number.

Here is Twilio's response "when sending the call out to another party, this will involve another leg to the call. If the call was to stay within Twilio and not head out to another party, this would be avoided."

We are looking for any other solution that could work for us.
BTW we estimate over 1500 concurrent callers to the conference line.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t possible. Twilio will remain in the call path. That is how CPaaS platforms work. Two call legs, and you independently control both via your application logic.